# async.parallel for PowerShell?

Tags: node.js, powershell, asynchronous

In node.js I've gotten really used to being able to send off several jobs using async.parallel, and then get them back in a nice `results[]` array in the callback.  There isn't any way of doing this in PowerShell is there?

The closest thing I've found is to use `Start-Job` inside a loop to kick off a bunch of processes; but then I have to use `Receive-Job` to get all of the results.

There wouldn't be something like running `Job-Wait` after the loop and then run `@results = Receive-All-Jobs` or something to that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wait-Job` waits for all jobs by default. So you could do:

```
$results = Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Am I misunderstanding what you need?

Comment: That seems like it...but when I run this it's really slow...is it really running in parallel?  In node it really moves...

Comment: @leeand00 it is slow! as you observed, it's starting a new _process_ for each task. It's not worth using jobs unless at least a decent portion of the tasks will take many seconds or longer. If you want something that performs better but works like jobs, check out the [PoshRSJob module](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) from PowerShell MVP Boe Prox.

Comment: @leeand00 yeah.. you have to really weigh the importance of parallelism perforformance vs. ease of deployment vs. ease of implementation. All the features in PoshRSJob use runspaces which are native, so you don't _need_ the module if you implement runspaces yourself, but that's a pain, hence why that module is great. Conceivably you could also embed the module into your script (check how its licensed, I don't remember), or just include the files near your script and `Import-Module` with the full path. Formal "install" is not needed.